# Meaning and interpretation of the definition of an ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, definition

The definition of an ordinary differential equation is
$$
F[x; y(x),y'(x), \cdots, y^{n}(x)]=0
$$
I don't understand the meaning and notation of the definition. What does $F$ mean?

Suppose I have a first order ODE, $n=1$, so $F[x; y(x),y'(x)]=0$:
\begin{align}
y'(x) &= \frac{1}{x} \\
\frac{dy}{dx}&=\frac{1}{x} \\
y(x)&= \log\lvert x \rvert+C
\end{align}
In this exemple, what does $F$ and $F[x; y(x),y'(x)]=0$ mean?

Or if I have
\begin{equation}
s'(t)=\cos 2t ,\qquad s(t)=\frac{\sin 2t}{2}+C
\end{equation}
How can I interpret the definition here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$F(x,y(x),y'(x),\dots)$ means a function (a special relation) of the variables $x, y(x), y'(x)$. So it could be any equation involving these variables. In your first example, $F(x, y'(x))=y'(x)-1/x$. In your second example, $F(t, s'(t))= s'(t)-\cos 2t$. So an ODE gives you a relation of $x, y(x)$, and $y'(x)$, (or with higher order derivatives).